# Layout issue depending on size

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'm having problems with a Table Layout. When a text is long in one of the buttons that the Layout has it shows the buttons wrongly. Here is what I'm talking about:

1- Here I've a table layout showed perfectly.:

[image]

2- Here's a grid with the problem that I can't fix:

[image]

The button is expanding when the text is long, I need a fixed size grid and I already tried putting on Width "match_parent" and "wrap_content". Here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/query_bank_mercantil"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/sample_1"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:text="@string/card_extra_tip_1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/sample_2"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:text="@string/card_extra_buy" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/sample_3"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:text="@string/card_extra_tip_3" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/sample_4"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:text="@string/card_extra_tip_3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/sample_5"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:text="@string/card_extra_tip_4" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set every button width to 0:

```
<Button android:layout_width="0dp" ... >
```